# Automatic Unseal for hashicorp Vault

Tags: python, python-3.x

While as a developer I naturally came across python many times in my life, I cannot recall writing any programs in python. So I'm sure my python is not very idiomatic. Let's fix it!

This is a script to automatically unseal [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) It is meant to run from within a docker container, but could be run stand-alone. It does not take any command line parameters, but takes input from either environment variables (a common method of passing configuration to a docker container) or from a config file, which I choose to be in json format.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/andrewsav-datacom/vault-unseal) and also follows.

The three inputs are:

- The url of vault you want to automatically unseal (e.g.   https://vault.rocks)
- The number of seconds to sleep between checks if the vault is sealed
- A list of unseal keys (you probably want a single key, since if you do not care for manual unsealing, it's unlikely that you created more than one)

In addition, you also can specify an environment variable to enable debug mode which turns on more verbose output.

```
import os
import sys
import json
import time
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import requests

version = "0.1"
envPrefix = "VU_"
config = "vault-unseal.json"

def PrintWithTimestamp(string):
  timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  sys.stdout.write(f"[{timestamp}] {string}\n")

def PrintDebug(string):
  if "VU_DEBUG" in os.environ:
    PrintWithTimestamp(f"DEBUG: {string}")

def PrintParameterError(name):
  PrintWithTimestamp(f"Error: {name} is not specified. Specify it either in {config} file, or as enviroment variable prefixed with {envPrefix}")

def NormalizePrefix(name, string):
  return name + string[len(envPrefix+name):]

def ReadSingleSetting(name):
  result = None
  try:
    with open(config) as data_file:    
      data = json.load(data_file)
    result = data[name]
  except (FileNotFoundError, KeyError):
    pass
  if envPrefix+name in os.environ:
    result = os.environ[envPrefix+name]
  return result


def ReadMultiSetting(name):
  result = None
  try:
    with open(config) as data_file:    
      data = json.load(data_file)
    result = { key:data[key] for key in filter(lambda x: x.startswith(name), data.keys()) }
  except (FileNotFoundError):
    pass

  result = result if result else {}

  prefix = envPrefix + name
  envResult = { NormalizePrefix(name,key):os.environ[key] for key in filter(lambda x: x.lower().startswith(prefix.lower()), list(os.environ.keys())) }

  finalResult = list({**result,**envResult}.values())
  finalResult = finalResult if len(finalResult) else None
  return finalResult

def ReadSetting(name):
  if name.endswith("*"):
    return ReadMultiSetting(name[0:-1])
  else:
    return ReadSingleSetting(name)   

PrintWithTimestamp(f"vault-unseal.py version {version}")

if "VU_DEBUG" in os.environ:
  PrintDebug("Dumping environment block:")
  pprint(dict(os.environ))

addressUrl = ReadSetting("ADDRESS_URL")
timeIntervalSeconds = int(ReadSetting("TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS"))
unsealKeys = ReadSetting("UNSEAL_KEY_*")

if not addressUrl:
  PrintParameterError("ADDRESS_URL")
  sys.exit(1)

if not timeIntervalSeconds:
  PrintParameterError("TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS")
  sys.exit(1)

if not unsealKeys:
  PrintParameterError("UNSEAL_KEY_*")
  sys.exit(1)

PrintWithTimestamp(f"ADDRESS_URL = {addressUrl}")
PrintWithTimestamp(f"TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS = {timeIntervalSeconds}")
PrintWithTimestamp("Number of unseal keys: " + str(len(unsealKeys)))

PrintDebug("UNSEAL_KEYS:")
for key in unsealKeys:
  PrintDebug(f"- {key}")
PrintWithTimestamp("If you do not see any output below, it means that the vault is contacted successfully and its unsealed")
PrintWithTimestamp(f"Vault will be contacted every {timeIntervalSeconds} seconds")
PrintWithTimestamp("Run with environment variable VU_DEBUG set to 1 for debug output")

while True:
  try:
    r = requests.get(f"{addressUrl}/v1/sys/seal-status").json()
    PrintDebug(f"status:{r}")
    if "sealed" in r:
      if r["sealed"] == True:
        PrintWithTimestamp("Detected sealed vault. Unsealing...")
        for key in unsealKeys:
          PrintDebug(f"key:{key}")
          r = requests.put(f"{addressUrl}/v1/sys/unseal", json = {"key":key}).json()
          PrintDebug(f"unseal:{r}")
        if r["sealed"] == True:
          PrintWithTimestamp("something went wrong, failed to unseal. Check the keys")
          PrintWithTimestamp(r)
          sys.exit(2)
        else:
          PrintWithTimestamp("Unsealed successfully")
    else:
      PrintWithTimestamp("Error: cannot find 'sealed' in returned json")
      pprint(r)
  except Exception as e:
    PrintWithTimestamp(f"Exception:{e}")
    PrintWithTimestamp(type(e))
    pprint(vars(e))
  time.sleep(timeIntervalSeconds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to not repeat much of [@Josay's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184159/84718) since it was written while I was poking with your code. But the key points still applies:

- The [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html) is your friend
- Follow PEP8 conventions
- Don't compare truth values using `== True`
- Don't repeat yourself

Speaking about the `logging` module, I simplified much of its use by removing the use of `pprint`. But you could add it back if you wish, here are [some recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11093236/5069029). Keep in mind, though, that using logging functions like `logger.debug` is meant to minimise the runtime needed to build the message string, so using f-strings in this context (which is rather nice otherwise) would lead to unwanted overhead in case of "non-debug" runs. Oh, and, by the way, `sys.stdout.write('…\n')` is better understood as `print('…')`.

You also happen to open, read and parse the configuration file thrice (once for each setting), this is a waste of resources. Read it once, use its values to update the `os.environ` dictionnary and search your settings in the resulting dictionnary.

The same kind of things happen when you try to unseal the vault. You use each key and then, check if the vault has successfully been unsealed. You can check after each key to avoid sending extraneous requests once the vault is unsealed. You can also use the [`for .. else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct to check that no keys unsealed the vault.

Proposed improvements:

```
import os
import sys
import json
import time
import logging

import requests


VERSION = '0.1'
ENV_PREFIX = 'VU_'
CONFIG_FILENAME = 'vault-unseal.json'


def configure_logger():
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, format='[%(asctime)s] %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger('vault-unseal')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if 'VU_DEBUG' in os.environ else logging.INFO)
    return logger


def read_configuration_file(filename=CONFIG_FILENAME):
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except (OSError, ValueError):
        return {}


def read_setting(setting_name, parameters, logger):
    if setting_name.endswith('*'):
        prefix = setting_name[:-1]
        setting = {key: value for key, value in parameters.items() if key.startswith(prefix)}
    else:
        setting = parameters.get(setting_name)

    if not setting:
        message = 'Error: %s is not specified. Specify it either in %s or as environment variable prefixed with %s'
        logger.error(message, setting_name, CONFIG_FILENAME, ENV_PREFIX)
        sys.exit(1)

    return setting


def unseal(base_url, time_interval, unseal_keys, logger):
    url = f'{base_url}/v1/sys/seal-status'
    unseal_url = f'{base_url}/v1/sys/unseal'

    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url).json()
            logger.debug('status: %s', r)

            try:
                sealed = r['sealed']
            except KeyError:
                logger.error('Error: cannot find \'sealed\' in returned JSON\n%s', r)
            else:
                if sealed:
                    logger.info('Detected sealed vault. Unsealing…')

                    for key_name, key_value in unseal_keys.items():
                        logger.debug('Using key %s (%s)', key_name, key_value)
                        r = requests.put(unseal_url, json={'key': key_value}).json()
                        if r['sealed']:
                            logger.debug('Unseal result: %s', r)
                        else:
                            logger.info('Unsealed successfully')
                            break
                    else:
                        logger.error('Something went wrong, failed to unseal. Check the keys.\n%s', r)
                        sys.exit(2)
        except Exception:
            logger.exception('An exception occured:')
        time.sleep(time_interval)


def main():
    logger = configure_logger()
    logger.info('vault-unseal.py version %s', VERSION)
    logger.debug('Dumping environment block: \n%s', os.environ)

    # Filter environment variables of interest
    settings = {key[len(ENV_PREFIX):]: value for key, value in os.environ.items() if key.startswith(ENV_PREFIX)}
    # Update values with those found in configuration file
    settings.update(read_configuration_file())

    # Retrieve required parameters
    address_url = read_setting('ADDRESS_URL', settings, logger)
    time_interval = int(read_setting('TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS', settings, logger))
    unseal_keys = read_setting('UNSEAL_KEY_*', settings, logger)

    logger.info('ADDRESS_URL = %s', address_url)
    logger.info('TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS = %d', time_interval)
    logger.info('Number of unseal keys: %d', len(unseal_keys))
    logger.debug('UNSEAL_KEYS:')
    for key, value in unseal_keys.items():
        logger.debug('- %s: %s', key, value)

    logger.info('If you do not see any output below, it means that the vault is contacted successfully and its unsealed')
    logger.info('Vault will be contacted every %d seconds', time_interval)
    logger.info('Run with environment variable VU_DEBUG set for debug output')

    unseal(address_url, time_interval, unseal_keys, logger)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As I commented in the other answer I do not quite get the advice about not using `== True`. I want detect a case, where json part is looking like `"sealed" :True`. Note that `"sealed" :"thingamabob"` will also evaluate to `True` when compared without `== True` and that's something I like to avoid. Any comments? Thank you for your answer, I find it useful.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh The "don't use `== True`" part comes mostly from [Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-annotations) (scroll a little bit above) and is mostly a matter of readability. The same as you don't say "if the weather is fine is true, then whatever", you don't compare truthiness using `if fine_weather == True: whatever()`. Now as regard to the fact that non-empty strings also evaluate to true, I'd just avoid API that could return booleans or strings for the same result like the plague.

Comment: One more question. Without `pprint` the dictionary is dumped as one long string, which is difficult to read. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh check the use of `pformat` in the provided link.

Comment: Indeed. If only people read the entirety of the answer with all the links the first time around they would not need to ask stupid questions ;). Apologies, my mistake. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 4):

**Style**

Your code does not follow the [Python Style Guide (known as PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
Along other things:

- you should use 4-space indents
- variable names should use `snake_case`
- constant names should be `UPPER_CASE`
- you should remove trailing whitespaces

I think the `PrintXXX` functions could have shorter names like `log` and `debug`. Also it could use the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html).

Also, it is a good habit to move your code actually doing things behind an [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Finally, it would be nice to have some documentation for the module and the different functions.

At this stage, the code looks like this (I haven't tested it).

```
import os
import sys
import json
import time
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import requests

VERSION = "0.1"
ENV_PREFIX = "VU_"
CONFIG_FILE = "vault-unseal.json"


def debug_is_enabled():
    return ENV_PREFIX + "DEBUG" in os.environ


def log(string):
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sys.stdout.write(f"[{timestamp}] {string}\n")


def debug(string):
    if debug_is_enabled():
        log(f"DEBUG: {string}")


def print_param_error(name):
    log(f"Error: {name} is not specified. Specify it either in {CONFIG_FILE} file, or as enviroment variable prefixed with {ENV_PREFIX}")


def normalize_prefix(name, string):
    return name + string[len(ENV_PREFIX+name):]


def read_single_setting(name):
    result = None
    try:
        with open(CONFIG_FILE) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        result = data[name]
    except (FileNotFoundError, KeyError):
        pass
    if ENV_PREFIX+name in os.environ:
        result = os.environ[ENV_PREFIX+name]
    return result


def read_multi_setting(name):
    result = None
    try:
        with open(CONFIG_FILE) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        result = { key:data[key] for key in filter(lambda x: x.startswith(name), data.keys()) }
    except (FileNotFoundError):
        pass

    result = result if result else {}

    prefix = ENV_PREFIX + name
    env_result = { normalize_prefix(name,key):os.environ[key] for key in filter(lambda x: x.lower().startswith(prefix.lower()), list(os.environ.keys())) }

    final_result = list({**result,**env_result}.values())
    final_result = final_result if len(final_result) else None
    return final_result


def read_setting(name):
    if name.endswith("*"):
        return read_multi_setting(name[0:-1])
    else:
        return read_single_setting(name)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    log(f"vault-unseal.py VERSION {VERSION}")

    if debug_is_enabled():
        debug("Dumping environment block:")
        pprint(dict(os.environ))

    addressUrl = read_setting("ADDRESS_URL")
    timeIntervalSeconds = int(read_setting("TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS"))
    unseal_keys = read_setting("UNSEAL_KEY_*")

    if not addressUrl:
        print_param_error("ADDRESS_URL")
        sys.exit(1)

    if not timeIntervalSeconds:
        print_param_error("TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS")
        sys.exit(1)

    if not unseal_keys:
        print_param_error("UNSEAL_KEY_*")
        sys.exit(1)

    log(f"ADDRESS_URL = {addressUrl}")
    log(f"TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS = {timeIntervalSeconds}")
    log("Number of unseal keys: " + str(len(unseal_keys)))

    debug("UNSEAL_KEYS:")
    for key in unseal_keys:
        debug(f"- {key}")
    log("If you do not see any output below, it means that the vault is contacted successfully and its unsealed")
    log(f"Vault will be contacted every {timeIntervalSeconds} seconds")
    log("Run with environment variable VU_DEBUG set to 1 for debug output")

    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(f"{addressUrl}/v1/sys/seal-status").json()
            debug(f"status:{r}")
            if "sealed" in r:
                if r["sealed"] == True:
                    log("Detected sealed vault. Unsealing...")
                    for key in unseal_keys:
                        debug(f"key:{key}")
                        r = requests.put(f"{addressUrl}/v1/sys/unseal", json = {"key":key}).json()
                        debug(f"unseal:{r}")
                    if r["sealed"] == True:
                        log("something went wrong, failed to unseal. Check the keys")
                        log(r)
                        sys.exit(2)
                    else:
                        log("Unsealed successfully")
            else:
                log("Error: cannot find 'sealed' in returned json")
                pprint(r)
        except Exception as e:
            log(f"Exception:{e}")
            log(type(e))
            pprint(vars(e))
        time.sleep(timeIntervalSeconds)
```

**Do not repeat yourself**

The check `if "VU_DEBUG" in os.environ` appears in multiple places. Maybe it would be easier to move this into a `debug_is_enabled()` function. Also, this could reuse the `ENV_PREFIX` constants like the other parts of the code:

```
def debug_is_enabled():
    return ENV_PREFIX + "DEBUG" in os.environ
```

**Choose a wise default value**

In `read_multi_setting`, you have:

```
result = None
// code_assigning_or_not_a_new_dict_to_result
result = result if result else {}
```

The last line only changes `result` if it is still `None`. It would be more straight-forward to write:

```
result = {}
// code_assigning_or_not_a_new_dict_to_result
```

**Do not perform useless operations**

In `read_single_setting`, you parse a file to get a value that will be overriden by environment variables. Maybe it'd be easier to perform the environ check first and parse the file only if nothing was found.

I'd write somethiing like:

```
def read_single_setting(name):
    if ENV_PREFIX+name in os.environ:
        return os.environ[ENV_PREFIX+name]
    try:
        with open(CONFIG_FILE) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        return data[name]
    except (FileNotFoundError, KeyError):
        pass
    return None
```

**Setting check**

You retrieve 3 different settings and check if there are not false. I am not sure if this is intended but for `timeIntervalSeconds`, you perform a conversion to int *before* the check. I'd probably perform the conversion after the check (also, sleeping for 0 seconds seems to be valid).

**Consistent return value**

In `read_multi_setting`, `final_result` is initially a list.
Then, there is:

```
final_result = final_result if len(final_result) else None
```

This seems confusing to me. Now, instead of `final_result` always being a list, either empty or not, it is now either a non-empty list or None. It make the function harder to use properly while making it more complicated. This could simply be:

```
return list({**result,**env_result}.values())
```

**Simplify dict comprehension**

You could call `prefix.lower()` *before* the loop.

You can use the `if` syntax in your comprehension in order not to call `filter`.

At this stage, you have:

```
prefix = (ENV_PREFIX + name).lower()
env_result = { normalize_prefix(name,key):os.environ[key] for key in list(os.environ.keys()) if key.lower().startswith(prefix) }
```

As far as I can tell, you don't need the conversion to `list`. Also, you can iterate directly over keys and values using `items()`:

```
env_result = { normalize_prefix(name, key): value for key, value in os.environ.items() if key.lower().startswith(prefix) }
```

**Comparison to True**

You don't need to write, `if value == True:`, you can simply write `if value:`.

**Use `get` to get value from dict with default value**

Instead of checking if a value is in a dict and then get the value, you could do both in one go.

```
        if "sealed" in r:
            if r["sealed"]:

        if r.get("sealed", None):
```

At this stage, the code looks like:

```
import os
import sys
import json
import time
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import requests

VERSION = "0.1"
ENV_PREFIX = "VU_"
CONFIG_FILE = "vault-unseal.json"


def debug_is_enabled():
    return ENV_PREFIX + "DEBUG" in os.environ


def log(string):
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sys.stdout.write(f"[{timestamp}] {string}\n")


def debug(string):
    if debug_is_enabled():
        log(f"DEBUG: {string}")


def print_param_error(name):
    log(f"Error: {name} is not specified. Specify it either in {CONFIG_FILE} file, or as enviroment variable prefixed with {ENV_PREFIX}")


def normalize_prefix(name, string):
    return name + string[len(ENV_PREFIX+name):]


def read_single_setting(name):
    if ENV_PREFIX+name in os.environ:
        return os.environ[ENV_PREFIX+name]
    try:
        with open(CONFIG_FILE) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        return data[name]
    except (FileNotFoundError, KeyError):
        pass
    return None


def read_multi_setting(name):
    result = {}
    try:
        with open(CONFIG_FILE) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        result = { key:data[key] for key in filter(lambda x: x.startswith(name), data.keys()) }
    except (FileNotFoundError):
        pass

    prefix = (ENV_PREFIX + name).lower()
    env_result = { normalize_prefix(name, key): value for key, value in os.environ.items() if key.lower().startswith(prefix) }

    return list({**result,**env_result}.values())


def read_setting(name):
    if name.endswith("*"):
        return read_multi_setting(name[0:-1])
    else:
        return read_single_setting(name)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    log(f"vault-unseal.py VERSION {VERSION}")

    if debug_is_enabled():
        debug("Dumping environment block:")
        pprint(dict(os.environ))

    addressUrl = read_setting("ADDRESS_URL")
    timeIntervalSeconds = int(read_setting("TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS"))
    unseal_keys = read_setting("UNSEAL_KEY_*")

    if not addressUrl:
        print_param_error("ADDRESS_URL")
        sys.exit(1)

    if not timeIntervalSeconds:
        print_param_error("TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS")
        sys.exit(1)

    if not unseal_keys:
        print_param_error("UNSEAL_KEY_*")
        sys.exit(1)

    log(f"ADDRESS_URL = {addressUrl}")
    log(f"TIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS = {timeIntervalSeconds}")
    log("Number of unseal keys: " + str(len(unseal_keys)))

    debug("UNSEAL_KEYS:")
    for key in unseal_keys:
        debug(f"- {key}")
    log("If you do not see any output below, it means that the vault is contacted successfully and its unsealed")
    log(f"Vault will be contacted every {timeIntervalSeconds} seconds")
    log("Run with environment variable VU_DEBUG set to 1 for debug output")

    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(f"{addressUrl}/v1/sys/seal-status").json()
            debug(f"status:{r}")
            if r.get("sealed", None):
                log("Detected sealed vault. Unsealing...")
                for key in unseal_keys:
                    debug(f"key:{key}")
                    r = requests.put(f"{addressUrl}/v1/sys/unseal", json = {"key":key}).json()
                    debug(f"unseal:{r}")
                if r["sealed"]:
                    log("something went wrong, failed to unseal. Check the keys")
                    log(r)
                    sys.exit(2)
                else:
                    log("Unsealed successfully")
            else:
                log("Error: cannot find 'sealed' in returned json")
                pprint(r)
        except Exception as e:
            log(f"Exception:{e}")
            log(type(e))
            pprint(vars(e))
        time.sleep(timeIntervalSeconds)
```

Comment: Thank you. `r["sealed"]` is a boolean so your suggestion regarding it does not work quite as intended. In particular `r.get("sealed", None)` condition will evaluate to `False` if the json value is `False`. This is not intended. I'm open to suggestions how to improve that part.